# Nextjs environment variables not working in js pages

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, environment-variables

I am creating a nextjs website. In my js file, I am fetching API data and I am assigning the token via `.env.local` file. But when i tried to access `.env variable` that I have created, it's not returning anything. I mean, it returns `empty/undefined`.
**My js file code:**

```
export async function getStaticProps() {
    const response = await fetch(`https:/mywebsite.com?token=${process.env.PRAISES_TOKEN}`);
    const body = await response.json();
    console.log(body);
    
    return {
        props: {
            naats: body
        }
    }
}
```

**.env.local**

```
PRAISES_TOKEN=MY_TOKEN
```

My `nextjs` project version is `12`.
In my git bash, it returns like this, no value of variable:

```
https://website.com?token=
```

**Update:**
The thing i have figured out is that when i assign any token/hash to env variable, then variable returns undefined. If i assign https url then variable works fine. So, i though to assign full url with token like `https://website.com?token=jhasvdiasvdjkagdg8catscuas`, but it doesn't work and returns undefined. Variable only works with https url values but without parameters.
This is strange.

Can someone please help me with this issue? I don't wanna expose my `token/api_token` to browser/public.

Comment: Have you tried logging your env outside of getstatisprops function?

Comment: Also, remember to restart your server whenever you change envs

Comment: @PCPbiscuit yes, It returns `undefined` in console log. I do always restart

Comment: Your code looks fine, it should work. Maybe you need to wrap value with `"`? Also, are you sure you are not destructuring `process.env`? Are you 100% using it inlined, like in your example? Or not accessing it using dynamic key stored in some variable?

Comment: @Danila Wrapping in " would be excessive and unnecessary but I agree with you this code should work. I just tried it out

Comment: Might be a stupid question but is ur .env.local located in the root folder?

Comment: @PCPbiscuit why wrapping would be excessive? Do you know how token looks like? What if it starts with `=` sign or something like that?

Comment: @PCPbiscuit yes my .env.local file is in the root folder

Comment: @Danila I have tried this before with double quotes and single quotes, but not working. I am surprised.

Comment: @Danila yes i did this `PRAISES_TOKEN="$2y$10pkjO0rOQ5byMiogat2$"` but undefined

Comment: You need to wrap like that: `PRAISES_TOKEN="$2y$10pkjO0rOQ5byMiogat2$"` and `$` signs need to be escaped like that `PRAISES_TOKEN="\$2y\$10pkjO0rOQ5byMiogat2\$"`

Comment: @Danila   Yes, i wraped it in code, forgot to add in comment, updated my comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Next.js will automatically expand variables `$VAR` inside of your .env* files, so you need to escape `$` signs with `\`, so if you token is `$abcd$ef` it should look like that: `PRAISES_TOKEN=\$abcd\$ef`

It is also good idea to wrap value with `"` quotes, because tokens also usually have other symbols like `=` and etc:

```
PRAISES_TOKEN="\$abcd\$ef"
```

[More info](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/environment-variables)

Comment: It worked, I was only wrapping it in double quotes. Now, as you told me about escaping `$` sign, it worked in this way. Thanks buddy